# What is the problem with node_modules (or npm) PPA on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, ppa, nodejs, npm, javascript

I started to use Ubuntu last year and since today I face really annoying problems. Firstly the problems were Reactjs with script errors which I couldn't even start a project, anyway I solved in different ways. And now I face problems

1. starting Reactjs with Typescript project like above error and
2. starting Vuejs project.

I googled problems and nothing helped. I don't know how to solve these kinds of problems permanently (I am not experienced on Ubuntu more) but I guess it is probably the wrong path problem in node_modules or npm folders. I checked all the permissions, installed packages with sudo, I don't think it is for a permission issue. In Windows10 it was in C disc and I can understand where the node_modules installed but on Ubuntu I didn't understand its logic yet, there are several folders and I think they are not well-structured (at least It is not clear for me). Btw, My folder structure looks really polluted, needs cleaning. If you want any more information from the system or whatever, I can provide all you want. I would be glad for any help!

My laptop: HP Pavilion g6, Ubuntu 20.04

**React Typescript project trying to start**

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app#overrides[0]': Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/2.8/node.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/2.9/node.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/3.0/node.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/3.2/node.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/node.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/util/isTypeReadonly.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/util/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/rules/adjacent-overload-signatures.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/rules/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/config-array-factory.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/getESLint.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/linter.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/2.8/node.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/2.8/node.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/2.9/node.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/3.0/node.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/3.2/node.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/node.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/typeguard/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tsutils/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/util/isTypeReadonly.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/util/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/rules/adjacent-overload-signatures.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/rules/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/dist/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/config-array-factory.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/lib/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/getESLint.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/linter.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/ramil/D:/Codes/dev-challanges/todo-app
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c react-scripts start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ramil/.npm/_logs/2020-12-29T20_34_08_108Z-debug.log
```

**Vuejs project problem on starting project**

```
> myapp@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel'
Require stack:
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at idToPlugin (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:145:14)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:184:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Service.resolvePlugins (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:170:10)
    at new Service (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:32:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js:15:17) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/ramil/D:/Codes/Vue-apps/myapp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c vue-cli-service serve

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ramil/.npm/_logs/2020-12-29T21_04_13_325Z-debug.log
```

**FIXED**

**1.** Changed the name of main folder (D:) from (D) - I don't know it affected or not but removed symbol.

**2.** I added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin` to ***.bashrc*** file

And also: I removed everything about node_modules before these and thanks to @Levente for responses above :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a few years back, so I may not remember all of it, but I recall that the default node installation on Ubuntu was tricky, because it's being referred to as `nodejs`, and it needed some alias to be set up to avoid problems. (I now don't remember where this alias went...)

**Update:** I have found something for the case when it's installed from the standard Ubuntu repo (NOT valid for the deb.nodesource.com PPA  variant!):

Before going further, confirm that node is indeed called `nodejs` on your system:

```
which nodejs
```

In case it returns a filesystem path, then — and then only — here is a oneliner:

```
sudo ln -s `which nodejs` /usr/bin/node
```

Note that this is [from a stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18130296) that last seen activity in 2017 (credit: @randunel); see more background there.

Nevertheless, I would probably not go that way; read on:

### NVM

I would recommend working with [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). It

- provides a different, well-managed node environment, thus allows you to leave behind Ubuntu's non-trivial node installation
- it allows you to switch back and forth between different versions of node and npm at ease, to match what each of your projects depend on
- for the previous reason, it's a "passport" to working in professional teams (which may need to simultaneously support both green-field and legacy applications)

The project's above linked github repo is quite helpful already, but [this npm Ubuntu installation guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04) may also come useful (the third option dealing with NVM).

Comment: I have used NVM before. I can change versions but it can make a problem for others (Reactjs). I don't want any other crashes on my current worked projects :)

Comment: Then see my update regarding the vanilla installation.

Comment: I did nodejs -v but it says: "Command 'nodejs' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nodejs" --- I did recommended command it updated smth and then when I checked "nodejs -v" again returns same response (nodejs not found). But "node -v" returns the version of node. Is there any difference between nodejs and node?

Comment: "... command it updated smth ..." I believe it did not update anything. As long as `which nodejs` doesn't return anything, the `ln` command will not generate a symlink. So your system should be still in the state that it was before. Also, I don't know how come you don't have a `nodejs` package. Seems like the first part of my answer does not apply to your installation.

Comment: "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (15.5.0-deb-1nodesource1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded." Yes it didn't update just returned this. It seems nodejs is already newest version. And still nodejs -v says: nodejs not found

Comment: Yes `which nodejs` doesn't return anything and `ln` too

Comment: I have just taken a closer look at the code samples in your question, and noticed you have `/usr/lib/node_modules/` on your system. Is this something that happens via a standard install? It surprises me. You should update your original question, and write there what steps have you taken to install node in the first place.

Comment: I haven't changed anything manually. Everything is standard ways I did. I have done same as DigitalOcean steps which you shared too. I doubt too there are different directories, as I said my question it is really polluted. Even I have reinstalled nodejs npm once and still same(

Comment: Maybe you installed it from the `deb.nodesource.com` PPA? (2. option in the linked doc) I see with this one, while the package is still called `nodejs`, like your install, the command in the terminal is `node` like on your machine, and unlike with the vanilla ubuntu repo install. The PPA version has already done something, regarding the aliasing.

Comment: Yes, If I am not mistaking, I remember that web page, I have installed it from the `deb.nodescourse.com` .  And now what would you recommend me to do?

Comment: Unfortunately I have zero personal experience with the PPA variant... I don't see support link on their github page either: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions I would still mention NVM at this point. It would offer a "clean" start, and even if it doesn't go perfectly smooth for you, being industry-standard, I think it would still be easier to find advice for NVM issues, as opposed to this Ubuntu-specific PPA. Also, it's worth to keep an eye on this post, maybe someone else chimes in...

Comment: Also, you can add the part about the PPA install to your original question; it's definitely an important aspect for those who are trying to help. Maybe consider adding a `ppa` tag as well.

Comment: Understood, I want to end the discussion with the last stupid question. Would you recommend removing all folders, packages related to nodejs and reinstall it again, I feel everything polluted and smth will annoy me again in the fututre. Appreciate your answers!

Comment: That would be a possiblity. But before you do, look up "completely remove package along with its PPA repository" or something similar topic on this forum's searchbar. It goes better when you get it right for the first attempt. Plus, if you really go for removing everything and done all the steps, afterwards go and check whether a small file (symlink) exists: `/usr/bin/node` If it does, and you want a completely clean system before a new reinstall attempt, remove that too, just to be sure.

Comment: After a complete removal, I would also search for `node_modues` in system-related directories (likely everywhere that is not under /home/yourusername) and remove them too if any gets left behind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117864/discussion-between-ramilabbaszade-and-levente).